# Calling api every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I am developing a room reservation app that interact with a third-party API. 
In order to make the app update most of the time, i need to make a GET call api to update the availability time every 30 seconds.

What i did is that i create a GET api call as normal and put it in an setInterval for 30 seconds.Its working but think about:  there will be : 2880 api calls in a day. is that normal ?

Do you think is that a good idea ? Is there any best practice doing it ?

Thanks

Comment: What about [web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)? Might be a better idea.

Comment: I am pretty new to web sockets. But i am relying on 3rd API. The only way to get the most updated availability time is make an api call.

Comment: Sounds like a DOS attack to me, if you were polling my API I would add you to a block list pretty quickly.

Comment: Well, the fact is that calling over an API every 30 seconds is not the best practice if you want real-time data. That's why you should start exploring web sockets, if you are using typescript, maybe websockets with Node.js could be easier for you.

Comment: Or if you are a .NET shop, SignalR may be a good alternative option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: If you're making the requests from the front-end, that's 2880 api calls in a day _per app_. You can cache the data on your server and serve that and maybe add an action users can make to refresh the data which will have your server make a call to the actual 3rd party with a throttle of 30secs/1min so at _worst_ it would be 2880 api calls if people are using your app 24/7.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to get live data every 30 seconds? Do you expect someone to make a booking trough this system every 30 seconds? Use caching instead.

If a customer makes a request you call the api, you can cache this response so another customer can share the same data if they come in the next 15 seconds or so. But if you don't get another customer for 15 minutes then all that polling is for nothing.

Comment: Well. I am making this app to display in a touch-screen in front of the room. So it need to get updated all the times. So people would know what's the schedule look likes.